# How did the knowledge of the pronunciation of the Divine Name get lost?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names, mesorah-tradition

I have heard that there are, in theory, 22 different ways to pronounce the Divine four-letter Name (Yud Key Vav Key) of Hashem and that the one correct way to say the Name has been lost.  How did that happen?

Comment: The whole story is a gemara in Kiddushin 4th perek on an amud alef.

Comment: @DoubleAA Did you mean ע"א א? (If you were being deliberately circumspect for some reason, feel free to delete my comment).

Comment: @Fred I hadn't looked it up yet! I just remembered which chavrusa I learned it with, and we learned the fourth perek of kiddushin together. Above I was just posting what I knew for now in case it helped someone.

Comment: @Fred Yep, that's the one.

Comment: @DoubleAA I figured that was more likely. :)